# Button moves automatically into "MapView"

Tags: android, android-studio, button, constraints, android-mapview

I have a Mapbox MapView and 2 buttons. One Button "button" (I know bad name) with text="zurück" is in the upper left corner as it should be. Now I want to have another button "noCameras" which is closed right to "button" but it should not get close to the right side of the screen.

But whatever I do, I can only put "noCameras" in the center between "button" and right screenside. If I want to put the constraints a bit differently or change the position of the button, it moves automatically into "MapView" and there I cannot change any position.

How it should look like: [How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYvD.jpg)

How it looks like when I dont change the position between "button" and right screen side. [How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8vgL.jpg)

The thing is that in the upper right corner there is a button that comes with the mapview and my button "noCameras" would hide this button from mapview.

I hope you understand what my problem is

my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="733dp"

        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="16">

    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="Zurück"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noCameras"
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="noCameras Button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        mapbox:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few changes you can make to make it work. It might be best if you remove the hard coded heights/widths so you can really utilize `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" >
    </com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zurück"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/noCameras"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        mapbox:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mapView"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noCameras"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="noCameras Button"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```